# smarty variables inside javascript

Tags: javascript, smarty

I am trying to use smarty variables inside javascript inside tpl

```
{literal}
<script language="javascript">
  google.load('visualization','1',{'packages': ['geomap']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);


  function drawMap() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addRows(4);
    data.addColumn('string', 'Location');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Number of links');

{/literal}{foreach from=$last5 item=link name=links key=index}
    data.setValue({$index},0,'{$link.location|replace:'\'':'\\\''}');
    data.setValue({$index},1,{$link.location_count});
{/foreach}{literal}

    var options = {};
    options['dataMode'] = 'regions';
    options['region'] = 'world';

    var container = document.getElementById('map');
    var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(container);

    geomap.draw(data, options);
  };
</script>
{/literal}
```

can you suggest me a solution please

Comment: What is your question? What doesn't work?

Comment: this doesnt work, is it syntactically correct ?

Comment: -1 --- Your link expired - this really makes this post unusuable for me!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply close the {literal} tag right before inserting the smarty variable, and re-open it again.

Or use {ldelim} and {rdelim} for the pieces of code where you assign values from Smarty.

Comment: should i need to do it for foreach tag of smarty

Comment: No Smarty tag can be placed inside {literal}{/literal}. When you need to place a foreach, a variable, an if, or anything else in Smarty, you must do it outside {literal}. If little JS is present, It might be better to omit the {literal}, and instead use {ldelim} and {rdelim} for literal curly brackets needed in JS.

Comment: i am really confused , i am trying lots of things but i could not manage to work it, can you please edit code and paste it for me

Comment: Actually, your code should have worked. The only real thing I've changed is escaped the single quotes in one place.
http://pastebin.com/J4ibLz1m
Also tidied up a bit.

Comment: And something else. It is a VERY, VERY good practice to generate JSON server-side, using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php . This way you won't have to escape anything, and you will only have to assign ONCE to a JS variable the JSON, then work with it in pure JS, with JS for, with absolutely no Smarty.

Comment: i tried your code but it did not work again, there must be strange thing , can we produce this code in different tpl and include it in this tpl ?

Comment: ah simple crazy thing , ifound it and it works now , i changed data.addRows(4); to data.addRows(5); thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
{literal}
function doSomething(myNumber){
  var result = myNumber/{/literal}{$myDivider}{literal};
  // rest of code...
}
// more functions...
{/literal}
```

or

```
{literal}
function doSomething(myNumber){
{/literal}
   var result= myNumber/{$myDivider};
{literal}
  // rest of code...
}
// more functions...
{/literal}
```

or

```
function doSomething(myNumber){ldelim}
   var result= myNumber/{$myDivider};
   // rest of code below...
{rdelim}

function doSomeMore(another){ldelim}
   alert('{$myHello}');
   // more code
{rdelim}
```

**OR (with Smarty 3.x and above, no *literals* etc necessary)**

```
function doSomething(myNumber){
   var result = myNumber/{$myDivider};
   // rest of code 
}
```

In Smarty 3 a left curly brace with a space character (space, tab or newline) next to it should not mess with the Smarty logic any more. Problems solved by using the new version :)

Comment: I've a similar situation here but little complex, look @ my code. `{literal}<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?client_id=2343434234&fb_only=true&redirect_uri=http://localhots/POC/manage_users.php?reg_type={/literal}{$regtype}{literal}&act_action=save_profiledata&fields=[{'name':'name'}, {'name':'email'}, {'name':'gender'}, {'name':'location'}, {'name':'birthday'}]" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no"  style="border:none"  allowTransparency="true" width="100%" height="360"></iframe>{/literal}` In this case it doesn't return full url but the value is retrieved.Any help?

Comment: Well, at least you have "localhots", not "localhost". Moreover, 'localhost' may be unacceptable, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707738/facebook-oauth-redirect-uri-problem-given-url-is-not-permitted-by-the-applicatio

Comment: This approach `{/literal}{$myDivider}{literal}` worked out for me.

Answer (score 0):

After trying (karvonen) answers [I did not try `{rdelim}` though, only tried `{literal}`], I got a problem with my `ajax` requests, it stopped fetching any date from server on loading after the smarty breaking in JS. So, what I did is I assigned the smarty value to a `hidden field` (I know this is not most smart thing to do) and then requested that value from JS and hence assigned it to a variable. 
Hope this helps.